# GStreamer: Caps negotiation failure

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I have a problem with linking of a two elements: avdec_h264 and avenc_mpeg4. I think that somehow these elements can't negotiate a capabilities of a data.

I've tested my pipeline with gst-launch:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location="rtsp://camera" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! avenc_mpeg4 ! fakesink
```

It have worked fine.

When I use my application where the pipeline is implemented:

```
    pipeline_ = gst_pipeline_new("default");

    if (!pipeline_)
    {
        return false;
    }

    receiver_ = gst_element_factory_make("rtspsrc",      "receiver");
    demuxer_  = gst_element_factory_make("rtph264depay", "demuxer");
    parser_   = gst_element_factory_make("h264parse",    "parser");
    decoder_  = gst_element_factory_make("avdec_h264",   "decoder");
    encoder_  = gst_element_factory_make("avenc_mpeg4,   "encoder");
    output_   = gst_element_factory_make("fakesink",     "output");

    if (!receiver_ || !demuxer_ || !parser_ || 
        !decoder_  || !encoder_ || !output_)
    {
        return false;
    }

    g_object_set(GST_OBJECT(receiver_), "location", "rtsp://camera", nullptr);
    // On this signal source pad of the receiver is being connected to
    // the sink pad of the demuxer.
    g_signal_connect(receiver_, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(on_pad_added), this);

    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline_), receiver_, demuxer_, parser_,
                     decoder_, encoder_, output, nullptr);

    if (!gst_element_link_many(demuxer_, parser_, decoder_,
                               encoder_, output_, nullptr))
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Everything links successfully. All elements change their state to PLAYING, but I get nothing: I do not get GST_MESSAGE_STREAM_START on the pipeline's bus.

Here is the graphs from gst-launch and my application:
[image: Graph generated by gst-launch]
[image: Graph generated by my application]

If I change avenc_mpeg4 to, videoconvert element, which is not an encoder, everything will works well. If I put an other encoder, I will still have current problem.

Probably I don't know about some particular things on how to work with the encoder. But I could not find solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

1. The code you posted above should listed for pad-added messages of decodebin. I am surprised if the code would work as is (maybe put the full code on a gist and link from here). See https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-pads.html
2. Insert a videoconvert between the decoder and the encoder.

Comment: I've create a gist: https://gist.github.com/simonenkos/9e31fc66b38a09afea362f1180c8296d
I've tried to add a videoconvert element, but nothing changes. 
And I also don't understand about the decodebin. I don't have such element in my pipeline. I only have a 'pad-added' signal handler for rtspsrc, which has a sometimes source pad.

Comment: I got tricked by reading demuxer, but that is just a depayloader, so this will actually work (part 1)).

Comment: Sorry, demux is just a depayloader. This works, so please disregard point 1. For the negotiation, you'll probably have to check the debug log :/

Answer (score 0):

Where are you linking reciever to demuxer ? that is needed as i understand.